# Can't open Script Editor from Google Sheets; only logged into one account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have multiple google accounts which I had seen in other forums caused some problems so I tried:

1. sharing the sheet with my other accounts,
2. logging out of all accounts and logging back in with my primary, and
3. opening it in incognito with only my primary account logged in.

In each instance when I click **Tools > Script editor** I'm sent to a page that says "Sorry, unable to open the file at this time. Please check the address and try again." This is a google workspace account for which I am the admin.

Is there some sort of permission that I'm missing?

Comment: See if it is listed and accessible at https://script.google.com

Answer (score 1):

The old "turn it off and turn it on again" strikes again. Restarted my computer and now it's working fine ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I really miss not having a reset button for my computer taking all the way back to boot up and starting again.